# How to develop SIP (VOIP) application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sip

I developed sip application in Android. and now I am developing it in Windows Phone 8. I am new in Windows phone and don't know anything that Which library should be use here? Do Microsoft provide free library for SIP?

Please any suggest me Which way will be best for developing or any source code or library or demo application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start from this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b).

There is a full sample app there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [boghe](https://code.google.com/p/boghe/), it's the SIP video client for Windows Phone 8 and Surface Pro. You'll learn a lot from there.

It also cover [VoIP apps for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) 8, which teaches you to integrate VoIP into WP8 experience